# How to rename tmux window with current running fish command?

Tags: terminal, tmux, fish

I wish to rename current tmux window to current running process in current pane with running fish. Here's my command I enter:

```
tmux rename-window $_
```

But instead of fish, I getting `tmux`. The problem, as I understand it - is because tmux itself is a process and $_ outputs it, where I need $_ to output process `before` using $_ as an argument.
The same behavior here:

```
echo $_
```

Outputs `echo`- because of that behavior I can not even see whats the current process is, all I can see is `echo`. So my question is I think is how to get `$_` "before current command", is there some way I can do that?

**Solution:**

Solution what I found is using that:

```
run-shell "tmux rename-window \"#{pane_current_command}\""
```

Strangely, you can not use rename-window outside of run-shell, because rename-window not interpolating tmux variables if runned inside tmux.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Create functions that are run when the `fish_preexec` and `fish_postexec` event is fired. See http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function

Also, to get the most recently run command use `history -n1`.